# Возобновление вопроса

Tags: обсуждение

Отлично,  если бы можно было  вопрос опять поднимать если он остался не решённым, любому зарегистрированному пользователю

Comment: Для этого можно использовать [конкурсы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Comment: Любая правка или ответ поднимает вопрос же

Comment: @АндрейNOP но ведь для этого нужна репутация, как и для конкурсов собственно. Ну или ждать утверждения другими участниками. А тут, видимо, хочется вжух.... взять и поднять. Чтобы все любовались.

Comment: @alexolut, ну тогда задать аналогичный вопрос, даже если его задубликатят, кто-то его увидит. А вообще, где-то же есть хороший ответ на этот вопрос, почему никто еще не задубликатил это?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, не надо аналогичных вопросов. Очередь на закрытие и так через край сыпется.

Comment: Дубликатом можно закрыть только к отвеченному вопросу. Так что если вопрос оказался похоронен неотвеченным, вполне нормально задать такой же. Ничего не насыплет в очередь. Только нужно добавить как можно больше деталей, иначе вопрос снова рискует быть похороненным без ответов.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight можно и к неотвеченным закрывать. Точно видел когда так делали.

Comment: @PavelMayorov у меня выводит Данный вопрос не имеет ответа, получившего голос «за» или «против». Может раньше можно было.